# VBA excel copy above cells when intersect

Tags: excel, vba, select, copy, intersect

I need to make Excel copy specific Range to the row, which is currently selected.

For example I have data like this:
[image]

And when I select A3, then I need to make Excel copy automatically Range C2:F2 to C3:F3, like this
[image]

And so on... If I select A4, I need to copy C3:F3 to C4:F4...

How is this possible please?

Comment: Should F3 be 60 then? And how is intersect involved and what have you tried? When you have your change event you can use Target object in conjunction with .Row to get the row above. You have lots of choice including OFFSET & RESIZE, Concatenating .Row value in range e.g. F & target.Row -1 etc.....

Comment: @TinMan yes, but I dont know how to determine in which row I currently am, and how to set which range to which I want to copy.

Comment: @QHarr F3 is formula (B3*E3). Intersect, because I thought of `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and there `If range Intersect then`, but I dont know, how to determine dynamically those ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds more like autofill to me.  You should probable fill down from `C2:F2`.

### Range.AutoFill

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Target.Row = 1 And Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2", Columns("A"))) Is Nothing Then
        With Target.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Range("C1:F1")
            .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

### Range.Copy

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Target.Row = 1 And Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2", Columns("A"))) Is Nothing Then
        With Target.EntireRow.Range("C1:F1")
            .Offset(-1).Copy Destination:=.Cells
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```